# My Custom Component is not working in react App.js

Tags: reactjs

In my [`components/`](https://github.com/Sukarnascience/Full-Stack_JS-React/tree/main/demo/src/components) folder I have created two components:

- using function-based components:

```js
import React from 'react';

const greet = () => <div className="App"><h3>Hello Sukarna Jana</h3></div>;

export default greet;
```

- using class-based-components:

```js
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class welcome extends Component{
    render(){
        return <div className="App"><h3>Hi, its Class Components</h3></div>;
    }
}

export default welcome;
```

but when I am trying to import that in `App.js` it's not running:

```js
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import greet from './components/greet';
import welcome from './components/welcome';

/*
 * dont know why greet and welcome tags are not working
 */
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <greet/>
      <welcome/>
      <h1>Hello Sukarna Jana</h1><hr/>  
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Custom components need to start with capital letters in JSX, otherwise it's `React.createComponent("greet", ...)` instead of `React.createComponent(greet, ...)`. Also please note "not running" isn't too helpful - provide the actual errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just reviewed the code and could find the issues easily,
You didn't keep the naming rules in your code.

```
<greet/> replace to <Greet/>
<welcome/> replace to <Welcome>
```

Also, you should change the name of the component.